# How do I show a Bootstrap 5 modal as a form success message upon clicking submit? Using Netlify for logging submissions

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, netlify-form

**Without using jquery** or PHP, how do I trigger a modal upon a successful form submission? I'm using Bootstrap 5.

My form submissions are being sent to Netlify.

```
            <form name="Index Page Form" method="POST" data-netlify="true" netlify-honeypot="hal-check">
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-flush" id="cardName" placeholder="Name" required>
                <label for="cardName">Name</label>
              </div>
              <p class="hidden">
                <label>
                  Fill this out if you're HAL-9000: <input name="hal-check" />
                </label>
              </p>
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-flush" id="cardEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                <label for="cardEmail">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control form-control-flush" id="cardMessage" placeholder="Message" required>
                <label for="cardMessage">What does your business do?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-6">
                <button class="btn w-100 btn-success lift" type="submit">
                  Send me information
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```